# I'm unable to load a URL using .load()

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to load a page using jQuery `.load()` function. I'm unable to see a page loading but other URLs are working just fine. Is it a problem with that specific URL or is there something wrong with the code. Url1 loads just fine but url2 shows nothing.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="load_here"></div>

  <script>
    var url1 = "https://stackoverflow.com";
    var url2 = "https://enquiry.indianrail.gov.in/xyzabc/LiveStation?stnCode=NDLS&toStnCode=CDG&withinHrs=8&trainType=ALL";

    $("#load_here").load(url2);
  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: You can not load the page with .load unless it's on the same server, Use IFrame instead and then customize it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem on `div` with `load` is that you must either be on the same domain as the page that's calling it, or enable Access-Control-Allow-Origin from the server side where that URL host.

Alternative:

Load whole page and use some CSS to hide that part which you don't want to show.

You can use `iframe` to load URL like below.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <iframe id="load_here" src="about:blank"></iframe>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var url1 = "https://stackoverflow.com";
      var url2 = "https://enquiry.indianrail.gov.in/xyzabc/LiveStation?stnCode=NDLS&toStnCode=CDG&withinHrs=8&trainType=ALL";
      $("#load_here").attr("src", url2);
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: But I want to show only a specific part of the page like we do in the load 

Like we do this

$( "#load_here" ).load( url+" #portion" );